# IntelliSense:error "Rectangle" is ambiguous

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

### I'm getting this error I don't know what is the problem trying to run it is showing IntelliSense error

I'm getting this error I don't know what is the problem trying to run it is showing IntelliSense error

```
namespace Capture {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Text;

using namespace System::Resources;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

ref class Form1;

class track
{
public:
    double area;
    int hitCount, missCount, age;
    bool justHit, isActive;
    Rect bbox;
    Point2f center;

    track()
    {
        area = 0;
        center.x = 1;
        center.y=1;
        bbox.x =1;
        bbox.y =1;
        bbox.width =0;
        bbox.height =0;
        age = 0;
        hitCount = 0;
        missCount = 0;
        justHit = false;
        isActive = false;
    }
};

const int maxObj=100;
track track_box[maxObj];
int numOfFrame =0;
int inputType = 0;
int alarmCount = 30;
//30 alarmcount means == 5 sec
int maxConsecutiveMiss=4;
double MinPersistentRatio=0.6;
double areaChangeFraction=0.20;
double centroidChangeFraction=0.20;
static  int sendNote=0;

public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

public:     
    static int initialX = 0, initialY = 0;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label17;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Panel^  panel3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label22;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label12;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label5;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox6;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  phnlbl;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  phntextBox;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  comboBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  comboBox3;
public: 

public: 
    static Rectangle *mRect = new Rectangle(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's definitely mis-tagged, but the ambiguity is most likely caused by something you've created called Rectangle and the Rectangle that is part of the System.Drawing namespace are conflicting. Did you happen to create a class that is confusing the compiler on which Rectangle you're trying to use there? To alleviate it, you should be able specify the namespace along with the object (ie, System.Drawing.Rectangle or MyFancyGraphics.Rectangle, etc...)